# Conditional formatting using list from another sheet

Tags: excel, excel-2007, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting

I have a spreadsheet for work with a list of claims from the previous month. Column A on Sheet1 contains the employer's alphanumeric group# (A2-A501). 
Sheet2 contains just a list (A1-A46) of group#'s that don't need review, and I'd like to set a conditional rule so that any row on Sheet1 where the value in the A column matches any of the group#'s in Sheet2, then the entire row formats appropriately to what I set (in this case, highlights red).

I researched online, but couldn't find any that would fit my specific scenario that also worked.

Comment: Tried using =INDIRECT("A"&ROW())="+Sheet2!$A$1:A$46" thinking if the cell in column A equaled anything in that range on Sheet2, then it would format (I use the Indirect rule for highlighting rows based on a cell in the same sheet). But I had found stackoverflow.com/questions/21119611 but can't seem to find the other one now which wasn't on this site.

Comment: I kept getting an error and I just realized I'm running excel 2007, so I believe I cannot reference another sheet, correct?

Comment: Brilliant! Worked perfectly! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems:

```
=MATCH($A2,vRange,0)
```

as a Conditional Formatting formula rule suited, where `vRange` is the name of Workbook scope given to the relevant range in Sheet2.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the entire selection you want the formatting to apply to.
2. Open the conditional formatting menu.
3. Select "Use a formula to determine which cells to format"
4. Set your format (fill red)
5. Enter the following formula

`=NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP($A1,Sheet2!$A:$A,1,0)))`

This assumes that on Sheet2, your group#s that don't need review are in column A.